# Replacing Cable Modem Motorola sb5101

Tags: cable, modem

I am having issues with ny current motorola modem sb5101. Since I own this modem (which was given to me by comcast in a promo offer), I would like to replace it.

What's a good replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Motorola SB6120 is a common upgrade from your current model. It supports DOCSIS 3.0 and has many controls and support from the majority of cable service providers.

Answer (score 0):

Your current service provider may have a recommended model; they may not have the best price for the device (so optional to look elsewhere for that model).

But if the ISP supplies it they may have an associated service/repair deal attached to it, that could be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Linksys makes a decent cable modem as well.  I have owned two of them and never had any problem with them until the lightening strike a couple of years back (which is why I have owned two of them).  Reliable almost to a fault, plug it in and it works.

Their current offering:
http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/products/Gateways